# UISlider Tracking Callout Unaligned to Thumb

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a `uislider` that has a callout bubble whose center X follows above the center X of the `uislider` thumb.

I tested it on an iPhone 7 and it works perfectly, and it also works perfectly on other devices once the thumb is moved.

The issue I have is that on initial load, the bubble and thumb should be aligned as it does when the thumb is moved, but on a device like an iPhone 8+ or iPhone SE, the bubble's center x is off from the thumb's center x (+/- 20-ish pts).

I believe the calculation to get the two objects aligned is correct since it works fine when you actually move the thumb, but something with the initial calculation of the thumb's x is off. With some console logs, the thumb's X would initially read as 180 pts but on touch the first value is actually 201 pts. The bubble then adjusts accordingly.

I am using a custom `uislider` subclass for gradients and such, and that could potentially be affecting it(?) but it's confusing how it still works on touch.

Any help would be appreciated.

On viewDidLoad (leading constraint is to safe area):

```
distanceSlider.setValue(Float(sliderValue), animated: false)

distanceCalloutViewLeadingConstraint.constant = distanceSlider.thumbCenterX - (distanceCalloutView.center.x - distanceCalloutView.frame.minX)
```

On distance change:

```
distanceCalloutViewLeadingConstraint.constant = distanceSlider.thumbCenterX - (distanceCalloutView.center.x - distanceCalloutView.frame.minX)
```

Thumb center X extension:

```
extension UISlider {
    var thumbCenterX: CGFloat {
        let trackRect = self.trackRect(forBounds: frame)
        let thumbRect = self.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: trackRect, value: value)
        return thumbRect.midX
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work any better? https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch12p598SliderBubble/SliderBubble/MySlider.swift

Comment: I can see two possibilities. (1) You are checking frame values in `viewDidLoad`. It's likely that it may be wrong. (2) You posted no code on the timing of (a) when you set the initial value of the slider along with (b) when you set the initial value of callout bubble.

Comment: Or this? https://github.com/alskipp/ASValueTrackingSlider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting below line in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. It looks like the view in with slider is added is not properly layout its size.

```
distanceCalloutViewLeadingConstraint.constant = distanceSlider.thumbCenterX - (distanceCalloutView.center.x - distanceCalloutView.frame.minX)
```

Why are you using custom image and adjusting according to slider value. You can directly use

`func setThumbImage(_ image: UIImage?, 
               for state: UIControl.State)`
check the reference apple doc link  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621336-setthumbimage

Comment: moving the line of code to viewDidLayoutSubviews() worked! do you think you'd be able to explain why just so i can fully understand?

Comment: @Chris I already stated in my answer that, you must have added slider in view which is having in issue in properly layout at viewDidLoad. ```viewDidLayoutSubviews()``` calls after all the view are layout completed and hence at this point the slider gets the right values and worked.